# Visual Studio Interface with MS Excel backend for Multiple Users to Run simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, google-apps-script

Until last month, I was creating Google WebApps with HTML interface, Java and Google Apps Script to let the users save data to Google Sheets.

That was working beautifully as all the users were able to save data to a single spreadsheet simultaneously without any data misses/issues.

This month onwards, I don't have the option to use Google Web Apps.

Therefore, I bought Visual Studio. Basically, I am trying to create an Interface using Visual Studio as I have some experience on Visual Basic codes, and then looking forward to save the data to MS Excel.

I have setup an FTP drive where I have saved a test .EXE file which saves their clipboard text to a single Rich Text File(I used the timer to save/read/refresh the file every few seconds). Since all the users have read/write/execute rights to that FTP folder, they are able to launch the .exe file simultaneouly from their systems and it's working perfectly. We are looking at a team of 100+ people.

Now the next step for me is to let them open the .EXE file where the data can be saved to a single Excel file. With Google Spreadsheets it was way too easy. But I need some guidance on how to do that with Microsoft. I studied through articles and articles to track the last updated row and push the data below that. I need tips from someone who has done something like this and if there's a better/efficient way of doing that.

Any help/article would be appreciated.

Comment: Common Access database with a distributed front end? I don't think you'll ever have multiple users editing the same Excel sheet simultaneously.

Comment: I was afraid to get this answer. It was just so much easier with Google. pass the variables from html to javascript and use google.script.run.myfunctions() to pass them to Google Apps script where I could use any spreadsheet key to append the result. God I miss that! @SmrtGrunt can you point me in the correct direction? I have not worked with Microsoft in a while. Any answer to my vision here? Thanks a bunch for replying anyway.

Comment: The Microsoft documentation actually has a decent run-down of your [options](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-03822632-da43-4d8f-ba2a-68da245a0446).

Comment: Thanks @SmrtGrunt Went through the link. Fair options but I must say there's nothing like Google.

Comment: Agreed. I just know the pain of working in a place where Google is not an option.